# ¿Cómo mandar alerta de stock crítico de un producto?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras en Laravel (PHP) y necesito saber cuándo hay bajo stock de un producto.

¿Cómo se podría hacer? Tengo mi controlador **Productos** en donde añado, edito y elimino productos.

Comment: Depende como quieres y cuando

Por ejemplo que haga una consulta todos los dias a media noche donde obtengas el stock de productos menores a 5 unidades:  podrias usar `cron job` , `eventos` en bdd.

Si quieres que cuando alguien compre un producto y solo quedan menos de 5, puedes considerar `procedimientos almacenados` como una opcion. 

Existen otras formas puedes investigar. 
Exitos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo sería crear una función en el controlador de productos que revise el stock de cada producto y envíe una alerta si el stock está por debajo de un cierto límite. Puedes utilizar la función de Laravel where() para obtener todos los productos con stock bajo y luego enviar una alerta usando la función mail() de PHP.

Por ejemplo:

```
public function revisarStock()
{
    // Obtener todos los productos con stock por debajo del límite
    $productos = Producto::where('stock', '<', 'stock_limite')->get();

    // Enviar una alerta por correo electrónico para cada producto con stock bajo
    foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        mail('email@ejemplo.com', 'Stock bajo', 'El producto '.$producto->nombre.' tiene bajo stock.');
    }
}
```

Puedes ejecutar esta función regularmente mediante una tarea programada (cronjob) para asegurarte de que se revisa el stock de forma periódica.

Si quieres comprobar el stock después de cada venta, puedes crear una función similar en el controlador de ventas que realice la comprobación después de cada transacción. La función podría ser algo así:

```
public function comprarProducto($idProducto, $cantidad)
{
    // Obtener el producto
    $producto = Producto::find($idProducto);

    // Restar la cantidad comprada al stock actual
    $producto->stock -= $cantidad;

    // Guardar los cambios en la base de datos
    $producto->save();

    // Revisar el stock del producto
    if ($producto->stock < $producto->stock_limite) {
        // Enviar una alerta por correo electrónico
        mail('email@ejemplo.com', 'Stock bajo', 'El producto '.$producto->nombre.' tiene bajo stock.');
    }
}
```

De esta manera, después de cada venta se actualizará el stock del producto y se enviará una alerta si el stock queda por debajo del límite.

Sin un código de lo que tienes hecho es difícil poder ayudarte correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

Depende de como quieras obtener el stock. Podrias agregar esto al controlador de **Productos**

```
    public function comprobarStock(){
        // Obtenemos el producto con la id.
        $producto = obtenerProducto($id);

        // Cuando queden pocas unidades enviaremos una notificacion.
        if ($producto->stock <= 5) {
        // Enviamos una notificacion del producto en cuestion.
            enviarNotificacion($producto);
        }
    }
```